# INSERT known values and also ones determined from JOINS

Tags: sql, sql-server

Please note this is a simplified example of what I have, the **Classification** table actually consist foreign keys to other tables to determine a document from Area, Category, Discipline, Doc Type 1 and Doc Type 2.

I have these tables:

**Document**

```
id | number | created_by_id | classification_id
```

**User**

```
id | first_name | last_name
```

**Classification**

```
id | category | document_type
```

I want to INSERT a new entry into `Document`. The information I know is:

- Document Number = "DOC001"
- Created By = "Bill Gates"
- Category = "Important"
- Document Type = "Newsletter"

I need to INSERT into the `Document` table, I have the "Document Number" but for the other 3 columns I just need to enter an integer of their foreign key ID.

I've seen examples on the internet using a SELECT statement to populate the fields, but this seems to only use fields retrieved from the SELECT query and doesn't include a known value mixed with this.

I hope that makes sense, and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join`s in the `insert`:

```
insert into document (number, created_by_id, classification_id)
    select number, u.id, c.id
    from (values ('DOC001', 'Bill Gates', 'Important', 'Newsletter')
         ) v(number, created_by, classification, type) left join
         user u
         on u.first_name + ' ' + u.last_name = v.created_by left join
         classification c
         on c.classification = v.classification and c.type = v.type;
```

It is, shall I say, non-traditional to store the first name and last name separately in a table, if you are going to be referring to someone by their full name.

Comment: Thank you for your response, my actual scenario is a bit bigger than the example I posted, so just finished writing it up. I'm getting an error `Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'IX_Document'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Document'. The duplicate key value is (DOC003_0).`. I can assure you the value "DOC003_0" does not exist. Is there something I should be aware of when using the SQL you provided? Thank you.

Comment: @squatman . . . I can assure you that it *does* exist, if the constraint is being violated.

Comment: Gordon Linoff thank you for your response. Please see additional answer post I have added with some images.

Comment: @squatman . . . (1) Nothing in your question is called `filename`.  (2) Such information should be added as edits to your question.

Comment: Gordon, yes as I said my actual scenario has a lot more tables and columns, I used an example in the question to understand the syntax required. Apologies I didn't realise I should edit my original, I will do this in future. I have just entered exactly the same information into each column manually using the "Edit All Rows" feature in Management Studio and it accepts it fine? I'm really confused and stuck.

Comment: Ah, so I removed the UNIQUE KEY and ran the SQL statement. For some reason it inserts the data 4 times. Not sure if it's relevant, but I JOIN to 4 tables...

Answer (score 0):

At a total guess (Column names are likely incorrect)...

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Document (number,created_by_id,classification_id)
SELECT V.Number
       U.UserID,
       C.classification_id
FROM (VALUES('DOC001','Bill','Gates','Important','Newsletter') V(number,FirstName,Surname, Category,[Type])
     JOIN dbo.[user] U ON V.FirstName = U.FirstName and V.SurName = U.Surname
     JOIN dbo.Classification C ON V.[Type] = C.[Type] AND V.Category = C.Category;
```

Comment: Larnu, thank you for your response. I have just posted my reply on the other answer.